# Where is swing.jar in jdk1.6.0?

Tags: java, swing

I read this tut
http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/uiswing/start/swingStart11.html

but I can't find swing.jar in my jdk1.6.0 folder ?

Comment: that guide is massively outdated (JDK1.1) try http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No `swing.jar` - the swing classes are in `rt.jar` (of the jre). It's a massive jar containing everything.

Sun (now Oracle) are trying to break that massive jar into modules, but it is not easy. [See this article](http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/is_the_jdk_losing_its). [Project jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) is aimed at modularizing the JRE. But for now - it's all in `rt.jar`

Answer (score 2):

The `javax.swing` package is included in `rt.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very, very old page discussing Java 1.1 which didn't include Swing.

These days Swing is part of the standard Java runtime library available out of the box.